# ratings of woo-commerce products are not displaying with woocommerce custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on product ratings, I only want to add ratings not reviews.
Here is my code. 
**Content-single-product.php**

```
<div class="description">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );


    ?>

</div>
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'my_print_stars' );


function my_print_stars(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id = $wpdb->comments.comment_ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
    AND comment_post_ID = $post->ID
    AND comment_approved = '1'
    AND meta_value > 0
");

$rating = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id = $wpdb->comments.comment_ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'rating'
    AND comment_post_ID = $post->ID
    AND comment_approved = '1'
");

if ( $count > 0 ) {

    $average = number_format($rating / $count, 2);

    echo '<div class="starwrapper" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">';

    echo '<span class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__('Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce'), $average).'"><span style="width:'.($average*16).'px"><span itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</span> </span></span>';

    echo '</div>';
    }

}
```

**themes/new/inc/woocommerce/hooks.php**
remove_action(

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_rating',10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_rating',10 );
```

Here is the code. The problem is ratings sections not displaying in product detail page. Is there anything wrong with this code? or I have to add new one.

Comment: did you move woo commerce plugin files to your theme?

Comment: means? no I didn't move.

Comment: Ok please have you integrated woo commerce pages into your backend something like Shop, cart my account etc, if not then add pages with the name shop and paste the woo commerce shortcode and check the URL http://yourwebsite/shop .....moving files mean copy woo commerce folder to your theme directory

Comment: Also, check your permalinks and reset it.

Comment: I am not getting what is you are talking about, but I have pages in backend in woocomerce folder as rating.php,single-product-content.php like this.

Comment: No dear, when you installing woo commerce its generating pages into admin end, something like shop into your WordPress admin pages. Please check there.